# jQuery animations being queued even with .stop parameter used

Tags: jquery

For some reason that I cannot quite figure out, my animation is being queued even though I am using the stop method. I have tried changing it to stop(true,true) but its not working. I've tried changing the effect but it also does not work.

```
 $('.box').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().find(".box-overlay").fadeIn("normal");
 });
 $('.box').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop().find(".box-overlay").fadeOut("normal");
 });
```

I would appreciate it if someone could educate me as to what I am doing wrong?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use .stop on the element that is animating.

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).find(".box-overlay").stop().fadeIn("normal");
});
$('.box').mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).find(".box-overlay").stop().fadeOut("normal");
});
```

And you can simplify it to:

```
$('.box').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).find(".box-overlay").stop().fadeToggle("normal");
})
```

Comment: See, I knew I was having a blonde moment, and that the answer was staring me in the face. Thank you. I'm an idiot :P

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer said, make sure you're targeting the correct element `.box-overlay`.

You can also consolidate your code using the hover method:

```
// mouseenter function
$('.box').hover(function() {

   $(this).find('.box-overlay').stop().fadeIn('normal');

// the next function is mouseleave
}, function () {

   $(this).find('.box-overlay').stop().fadeOut('normal');

});
```

Comment: or even `$('.box').hover(function() { $(this).find('.box-overlay').stop().fadeToggle('normal'); });`

Comment: yeah thats even more terse, nice!